# How to constrain the results to a specific post_type on tag archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, taxonomy, tags, archives

I registered three custom post types to a single taxonomy( the default `post_tag` taxonomy).

When I access `example.com/tag/foo`, I got the posts that have a `foo` tag, and the posts were taken from all the three custom post types.

I want to constrain the posts to one specific post type.

Say when I access `example.com/tag/foo/?post_type=BAR` or `example.com/tag/foo/post_type/BAR`, then I should get all the posts that have a `foo` tag AND the `post_type` of the posts is `BAR`.

I've tried to set the main-query's `query_var` to `post_type => BAR` in `pre_get_post‌s` but that won't work.. Because I have to paginate the posts, so I can't just simply use the `WP_Query` to query and show them all. So please help!

Comment: You're looking for pre_get_posts with a function that filters the results for queries on your custom taxonomy archive: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts This post (& its comments) have a ton of examples: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/make-archives-php-include-custom-post-types/

Comment: As I said, I've tried setting the `post_type` in `pre_get_post‌s`, but that will take me to the custom post type archive page.

Comment: Hmm, maybe can you post your code with pre_get_posts so we can see why that didn't work? I will put in an answer below with a function that works for me using pre_get_posts...

Comment: I figured it out. It's the bug of the WordPress I have to say. Because on the tag archives page with the query string `?&post_type=FOO` appended, both `is_post_type_archive()` and `is_tag()` returns `true`, and a page should not being both a post type archive and a tag archive, it should always be a single type of page. I guess I have to report a bug to the WordPress team...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
function namespace_add_custom_types( $query ) {
  if( is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array(
     'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'nav_menu_item'));
      return $query;
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'namespace_add_custom_types' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WP_Query` for this. By default it will paginate unless you tell it not to by passing it the `'nopaging'` parameter and set it to `true`.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
                         // Your CPT parameters
                         'nopaging' => true,
                     )
);
```

In your case, you would simply rewrite the query to tell WordPress how many posts you want, etc.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
                              'post_type' => 'review',
                              'posts_per_page' => 15,
                            )
);
```

So this query would grab all post types with the slug of `review` and show 15 posts per page.

Comment: No, I do want pagination.

Comment: Ok, I misread what you wrote in your question. I thought you wanted pagination in general but not for these.

Comment: I updated my answer.